# Using for Loop in "C" programming

Tags: loops, for-loop

I need to add a loop to print each an every score of particular experiment terms.now in my code I can only get one score (check my loop condition). So it's need to be repeat 07-08 times.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{   
    int diff;
    int experiments[8]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,};
    int measurements[8] ={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int real[8]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int counter;
    int score;
    char output;
    printf("Please enter the real value for %d \n\n",real[0]);
    scanf("%d",&real[0]);
    printf("Please enter the real value for %d \n\n",real[1]);
    scanf("%d",&real[1]);
    printf("Please enter the real value for %d \n\n",real[2]);
    scanf("%d",&real[2]);
    printf("Please enter the real value for %d \n\n",real[3]);
    scanf("%d",&real[3]);
    printf("Please enter the real value for %d \n\n",real[4]);
    scanf("%d",&real[4]);
    printf("Please enter the real value for %d \n\n",real[5]);
    scanf("%d",&real[5]);
    printf("Please enter the real value for %d \n\n",real[6]);
    scanf("%d",&real[6]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",real[7]);
    scanf("%d",&real[7]);
    printf("Now your turn");
    printf("\nPlease enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[0]);
    scanf("%d",&experiments[0]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[1]);
    scanf("%d",&experiments[1]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[2]);
    scanf("%d",&experiments[2]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[3]);
    scanf("%d",&experiments[3]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[4]);
    scanf("%d",&experiments[4]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[5]);
    scanf("%d",&experiments[5]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[6]);
    scanf("%d",&experiments[6]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[7]);
    scanf("%d",&experiments[7]);
    printf("Congratulations ! you have all done.here is the result");
    printf("\nReal value for 0 : %d ! but your experiment value is : %d",real[0],experiments[0]);
    printf("\nReal value for 1 : %d ! but your experiment value is : %d",real[1],experiments[1]);
    printf("\nReal value for 2 : %d ! but your experiment value is : %d",real[2],experiments[2]);
    printf("\nReal value for 3 : %d ! but your experiment value is : %d",real[3],experiments[3]);
    printf("\nReal value for 4 : %d ! but your experiment value is : %d",real[4],experiments[4]);
    printf("\nReal value for 5 : %d ! but your experiment value is : %d",real[5],experiments[5]);
    printf("\nReal value for 6 : %d ! but your experiment value is : %d",real[6],experiments[6]);
    printf("\nReal value for 7 : %d ! but your experiment value is : %d",real[7],experiments[7]);
    printf("Please wait........");
    {
        for(counter=0;counter<8;counter++)
           diff=abs(experiments[counter]-real[counter])*100 /real[counter];
        if (diff<1)
        {
           printf("\nThe score is = 8");
        }
        else if(diff<10)
        {
           printf("\nThe score is = 4");
        }
        else
        {
          printf("\nThe score is =0");
        }
     }
    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Brackets are wrong. Please do like this:

```
 for(counter=0;counter<8;counter++)
 {
 ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(…………){
  these lines will be run...
 }
```

now,

```
 for(…………)
  line A
  line B
```

the line A will be run.

```
  for(counter=0;counter<8;counter++){
    diff=abs(experiment[counter]-real[counter])*100 /real[counter];
    if (diff<1)
    {
    printf("\nThe score is = 8");
    }
    else if(diff<10)
    {
       printf("\nThe core is = 4");
    }
     else
    {
      printf("\nThe score is =0");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{   
 int diff,experiments[8],measurements[8],real[8],counter;
    int score;
    char output;
    printf("Please enter the real value for %d \n\n",real[0]);
    scanf("%d",&real[0]);
    printf("Please enter the real value for %d \n\n",real[1]);
    scanf("%d",&real[1]);
    printf("Please enter the real value for %d \n\n",real[2]);
    scanf("%d",&real[2]);
    printf("Please enter the real value for %d \n\n",real[3]);
    scanf("%d",&real[3]);
    printf("Please enter the real value for %d \n\n",real[4]);
    scanf("%d",&real[4]);
    printf("Please enter the real value for %d \n\n",real[5]);
    scanf("%d",&real[5]);
    printf("Please enter the real value for %d \n\n",real[6]);
    scanf("%d",&real[6]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",real[7]);
    scanf("%d",&real[7]);
    printf("Now your turn");
    printf("\nPlease enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[0]);
    scanf("%d",&experiments[0]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[1]);
    scanf("%d",&experiments[1]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[2]);
    scanf("%d",&experiments[2]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[3]);
    scanf("%d",&experiments[3]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[4]);
    scanf("%d",&experiments[4]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[5]);
    scanf("%d",&experiments[5]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[6]);
    scanf("%d",&experiments[6]);
    printf("Please enter the measurement for %d \n\n",measurements[7]);
    scanf("%d",&experiments[7]);
    printf("Congratulations ! you have all done.here is the result");
    printf("\nReal value for 0 : %d ! but your experiment value is : %d",real[0],experiments[0]);
    printf("\nReal value for 1 : %d ! but your experiment value is : %d",real[1],experiments[1]);
    printf("\nReal value for 2 : %d ! but your experiment value is : %d",real[2],experiments[2]);
    printf("\nReal value for 3 : %d ! but your experiment value is : %d",real[3],experiments[3]);
    printf("\nReal value for 4 : %d ! but your experiment value is : %d",real[4],experiments[4]);
    printf("\nReal value for 5 : %d ! but your experiment value is : %d",real[5],experiments[5]);
    printf("\nReal value for 6 : %d ! but your experiment value is : %d",real[6],experiments[6]);
    printf("\nReal value for 7 : %d ! but your experiment value is : %d",real[7],experiments[7]);
    printf("Please wait........");
    for(counter=0;counter<8;counter++)
    {
       diff=abs(experiments[counter]-real[counter])*100 /real[counter];
        if (diff<1)
        {
        printf("\nThe score is = 8");
        }
        else if(diff<10)
        {
           printf("\nThe score is = 4");
        }
         else
        {
          printf("\nThe score is =0");
        }
    }   
}
```

try it